# Translating MIPS Assembly into C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

```
add $s0, $s0, $s1
add $s0, $s0, $s2
add $s0, $s0, $s3
add $s0, $s0, $s4
```

No other instructions are given so I just assumed $s0=a, $s1=b, $s2=c, $s4=d. This is what I have for the translated C code but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
a=a+b+c+d
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct.  You left out `$s3`.  Assuming:

```
 register  variable
   $s0        a
   $s1        b
   $s2        c
   $s3        d
   $s4        e
```

You'd have something along the lines of:

```
   a = a + b + c + d + e;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
add $s0, $s0, $s1 # $s0 = $s0 + $s1
add $s0, $s0, $s2 # $s0 = $s0 + $s2 (= $s0 + $s1 + $s2)
add $s0, $s0, $s3 # $s0 = $s0 + $s3 (= $s0 + $s1 + $s2 + $3)
add $s0, $s0, $s4 # $s0 = $s0 + $s4 (= $s0 + $s1 + $s2 + $s3 + $s4)
```

Therefore the code above will do

```c
$s0 += $s1 + $s2 + $s3 + $s4;
```

As a sidenote, the above code introduces unnecessary dependencies which may make execution slower because the instructions cannot run parallelly. Reorder the instructions as

```
add $t0, $s0, $s1
add $t1, $s2, $s3
add $s0, $s4, $t0
add $s0, $s0, $t1
```

may be better